# Using multi threading to simulate 6 users logging in using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a function using selenium to login to a page in a different tab for each credential in a dictionary of usernames and passwords. I have 6 users so I will have 6 tabs open. I want to keep track of each tab I have open so I can navigate back to a specific tab.

This is what I have tried:

```
users = {'userA': 'pass',
         'userB': 'pass2',
         'userC': 'pass3',
         'userD': 'pass4',
         'userE': 'pass5',
         'userF': 'pass6',
         }
tab_names = []
count = 0
for key in users:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "name-field"))
            # name_input = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'name-field')
        )
        element.send_keys(key)
        browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password-field').send_keys(users[key])
        second_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-button'))
        )
        second_element.click()
        sleep(3)
        browser.execute_script("window.open('https://somepage/login')")
        count+=1
        tab_names.append(str(count))
        # sleep(10)
        browser.find_element(By.ID, 'login-button').click()
    finally:
        browser.quit()
```

My code is not doing what I intend, this function opens a tab, logs in with specific credentials and closes the window without opening a new tab to login with the next credential.

Comment: using Quit() method will close the driver and browser, so it's closed on the first iteration.  You'll also need to switch the driver to the new window handle(s).  getWindowHandle() (gets current handle) and getWindowHandles() (gets all handles) are useful methods for getting the new tab's handle.  Then use driver's switchTo() method to switch to the new handle.

Comment: @pcalkins do you mind adding this as an answer